# Emebed my service installer into another app installer and install silently

Tags: c#, windows-services, installation

I developed a windows service in C# and created MSI installer for it. Now what I want is to install my service silently when installing my another application written in c#. Is there any possibility to do it?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "silently". There is an API to register services, so it is possible to install a service programmatically. Many programs do it (adobe reader, itunes..) However, the user that installs the program needs to have admin privileges, or you need to get them through UAC.